# using custom plugin on run-time created table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating a table run time in the memory and later appending it to dom.
Something like this :

```
var myTable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "dataMatrixtable" }).attr({class: "tipTable",cellpadding: "5",cellspacing: "0"});
myTable.appendTo(this.top.$("#tableContainer"));
```

This.top because table is in a iframe.

Now I wrote a plugin something like this.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        mailServer : function() {
            this.addClass("blah");
        },
    })
})(jQuery)
```

when i am calling this function mailServer after appending the table to dom

```
$("#dataMatrixtable").mailServer();
```

or

```
this.top.$("#dataMatrixtable").mailServer();
```

either way its not working (not appending the class)

Where as it works for the elements which is already in the dom when page loads..

How to solve this issue.please help

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a way its working now .. 
What I did is

```
myTable.mailServer(); (its working and I am able to access the plugin funciton mailServer()
```

In place of doing

```
 $("#dataMatrixtable").mailServer();
```